# No repository for _ was found. Looks like this entity is not registered…

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I need your help because this is really starting to get to me.

I can't seem to solve this error with TypeORM and NestJS.

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "CommentRepository" was
> found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default"
> connection?

The error is pretty clear but I don't understand how the config `entities: []` works.

The worst thing is that before, everything was working perfectly. But after a little refactoring of my structure, it doesn't work anymore.

My folder structure :

```bash
.
├── app.module.ts
├── authentication
│   ├── auth.controller.ts
│   ├── auth.module.ts
│   ├── auth.service.ts
│   ├── dto
│   └── enums
├── common
│   ├── constants
│   ├── decorators
│   ├── enums
│   ├── exceptions
│   ├── guard
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── interceptor
│   ├── interfaces
│   ├── middlewares
│   ├── pipes
│   ├── serializers
│   ├── strategies
│   └── validations
├── config
│   ├── app
│   ├── cache
│   └── database # Here are my database config
├── database
│   ├── config.schema.ts
│   ├── factories
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── providers
│   └── seeders
├── locales
│   ├── en
│   └── fr
├── mails
│   ├── mail.module.ts
│   ├── mail.service.ts
│   ├── reset-password
│   ├── templates
│   └── verification
├── main.ts
└── models # Here are my models
    ├── address
    ├── booking
    ├── comment
    ├── company
    ├── container
    ├── listing
    ├── office
    ├── port
    └── user
```

My database config :

```bash
...
├── config
│   ├── app
│   ├── cache
│   └── database
│       └── postgres
│           ├── config.module.ts
│           ├── config.service.ts
│           └── configuration.ts
...
```

My database config service and the app module

```js
// config.service.ts

import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class PostgresConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: this.configService.get<string>('DB_HOST'),
      port: this.configService.get<string>('DB_PORT'),
      username: this.configService.get<string>('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: this.configService.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.configService.get<string>('DB_DATABASE'),
      entities: ['../../models/**/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      migrations: ['src/database/migrations/*.ts'],
      migrationsRun: true,
      cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
      },
    };

    console.log(this.configService.get<string>('DB_HOST'));
  }
}
```

```js
// app.module.ts

...
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: [`.env.${process.env.STAGE}`],
      validationSchema: configValidationSchema,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: PostgresConfigService,
      inject: [PostgresConfigService],
    }),
...
]
```

Comment: You must change ` entities: ['../../models/**/entities/*.entity.{ts,js}'],` property because you changed your folder structure. For examples your models filename no longer has `entity.ts` part or they are not longer in `entities` folder.

Comment: I tried relative path, absolute path and even just an array of entities (```entities: [Comment, User, etc.]```).
But nothing worked.